# Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. when using Map.reduce(max)

Tags: flutter, dart, mapreduce, dart-null-safety

I want to get the max value from a List. But since i migrated to null safety my code doesnt work anymore:

```
weightChart = [45.3, 21.5, 521.3];
weightChart.reduce(max)
```

I get the error:

```
Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.  Tried to infer 'double?' for 'T' which doesn't work: Type
 parameter 'T' is declared to extend 'num' producing 'num'. The type 'double?' was inferred from:
 Function type declared as 'T Function<T extends num>(T, T)' used where 'double? Function(double?,
 double?)' is required.  Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.
```

Comment: what was the data type of your `weightChart`

Comment: I fixed the issue: I used <double?> but it needs to be <double>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  List<double> weightChart = [45.3, 21.5, 521.3];
  print(weightChart.reduce(max));
}
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, I had an error of OP because I was passing a parameter to reduce that can be null. Fixed with `element ?? 0` to ignore the missing ones.